# Why is $\lim_{x\to 0} x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$ the "additive equivalent" of $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, terminology

From Finch ([2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA12), Mathematical Constants):

[image]

**My question:**

Why is $\lim_{x\to 0} x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$ the "additive equivalent" of $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$? (What is "additive equivalent"?)

Comment: If I had to take a guess, the author's use of the phrase "$1+x$ rushes toward the multiplicative identity" means that they intended use the phrase "$x$ rushes to the additive identity" (being $0$) in a continuation of their tug of war analogy. The first limit involves infinity and the "multiplicative identity", then the second limit involves infinity and the "additive identity".

Comment: I have given a "Suitable" Answer to the question , @NinadMunshi , just informing you in case you have not seen it yet.

Answer (score 4):

**In Multiplicative Case :**

Consider $Y=(1+x)$ ( where $1$ is the Multiplicative Identity ) multiplied by itself $1/x$ times , which gives $(1+x)^{1/x}$ : taking limit when $Y$ tends to the Multiplicative Identity gives $e$.

**In Additive Case :**

Consider $Z=(0+x)$ ( where $0$ is the Additive Identity ) added to itself $1/x$ times , which gives $(0+x) \times {1/x}$ : taking limit when $Z$ tends to the Additive Identity gives $1$.

**In General Case :**

Consider $X=(I+x)$ where $I$ is the Identity for Operator $\circ$. Perform Operation $\circ$ on $X$ , $1/x$ times. Then take limit when $X$ tends to $I$ ( which might make $x$ tend to $0$ , matching some Identity , though that is occurring co-incidentally )

When $\circ=\times$ , we get limit $e$.
When $\circ=+$ , we get limit $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a clue:

$$(1+x)^{\frac1x}=e^{\frac1x\cdot\ln(1+x)}$$

when $x\to0, ~\ln(1+x)\sim x$, then we have

$$x\cdot\ln(1+x)\sim \frac1x\cdot x$$
Maybe this is where the "additive equivalence" coming from, then we get

$$(1+x)^{\frac1x}=e^{\frac1x\cdot\ln(1+x)}\sim e^{\frac1x\cdot x}\to e$$